# Android: list all recorded files

Tags: android

I want to fetch an arraylist of all sounds recorded with the default sound recorder. How is this possible? I am using the following code to fetch all sounds from the sdcard, but it doesn't contain recorded sounds at all, which have the 3ga extension.

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
String[] projection = {
  MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
};
Cursor cursor = ((Activity) ctx).managedQuery(
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  projection,
  selection,
  null,
  null
);
if(cursor != null) {
  while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    songs.add(new Song(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(4)));
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no "default sound recorder" app in Android.

Comment: yes there is, there is proper intent that opens that application

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "there is no single default sound recorder app in Android". Device manufacturers are welcome to have whatever they want support that `Intent`, and those apps are welcome to store the sound files wherever they want.